# Normalization does not preserve code point

Tags: unicode, character-encoding

Can anyone please explain me why the NFD normalization from U+2126 (Ω) and U+03A9 (Ω) results in the same representation and does not preserve the code point? I would have expected this behaviour for NFKD and NFKC (and for characters with diacritics) only.

```
result1 = unicodedata.normalize("NFD", u"\u2126")
result2 = unicodedata.normalize("NFD", u"\u03A9")
print("NFD: " + repr(result1))
print("NFD: " + repr(result2))
```

Output:

```
NFD: u'\u03a9'
NFD: u'\u03a9'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These are known as "singleton decompositions", and exist for characters like U+2126 (Ω) that are present in Unicode for compatibility with existing standards. They are not "compatibility decompositions" (like U+1D6C0 ) because they are both visually and semantically identical to another code point (in this case, U+03A9 Ω).

Because they essentially duplicate another code point, one is chosen as the "preferred form" and the other is always replaced by it when normalised (into any form). The first form is essentially deprecated.

Comment: Thanks for pointing me to this answer, I have marked [my question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33945665) as a duplicate. This explains why the ICU normalizer works the way it does - [details here, for reference](http://unicode.org/reports/tr15/#Primary_Exclusion_List_Table). I'm still having a hard time understanding why Unicode works that way. Is a Greek question mark (U+037E) *really* semantically identical to a semicolon (U+003B)? Or another example: U+2000 decomposes to U+2002. It looks like they were both added at the same time - then why even include U+2000 in the standard?

Comment: It feels like the more I learn about Unicode, the less I know... I guess what I'm really looking for is a place to discuss such questions, like a mailing list or newsgroup or forum. So far, I haven't been able to find one.

Comment: Semantically identical? Not at all. That's why both code points exist—if you need the semantic distinction, you shouldn't normalise. However, the in many cases this can be determined from context and having two visually identical characters just causes problems, so the Unicode standard gives them canonical equivalents. The Unicode Consortium operates a [mailing list](http://unicode.org/consortium/distlist-unicode.html) you might find helpful.